# An AJAX HTTP error ocurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 (while trying to rebuild content access perms)

Tags: 7, ajax, debugging, users, http-request

I have installed a module that ask me everytime to rebuild content Access Permissions, but every time I try to do it, it shows me an error I do not have idea why is it happening. Please help

```
An AJAX HTTP error ocurred. HTTP Result Code:  500 Debugging information follows: Path: /batch?id=172&op=do Status Text: Service unavailable (with message)
Response Text:
```

Please check the image for more details
[image]

Comment: Could you mention which module did you installed? How much content (nodes) do you have on your site?

Comment: I installed the sub-groups for organic groups module https://www.drupal.org/project/og_subgroups and I do not have much nodes like 100 nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this was the server, the server was refusing the ajax request, maybe a php memory problem I have migrated my drupal website to a VPW

Comment: I am facing same problem, i restarted the apache and mysql but still getting the ajax 500 error in my complete site where we are using ajax

Comment: Try another hosting